# Logic in while-statement

Tags: php, sql, pdo, while-loop

For a search I am using this code snippet:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT id,username FROM `users` WHERE `username` LIKE :keyword');
    $keyword = "%".$data."%";
    $stmt->bindParam(':keyword', $keyword, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();   
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $row_array['id'] = $row['id'];
        $row_array['user'] = utf8_encode($row['username']);
        array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
    }
```

Instead of getting only those value´s which are "LIKE keyword", I get every result from my table "users", why is this happening?

Comment: Looks like `$data` is simply empty, thus you look for `LIKE '%%'` ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check if $data is empty before preparing the query:

```
if(!empty($data) && is_string($data)){
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT id,username FROM `users` WHERE `username` LIKE :keyword');
    $keyword = "%".$data."%";
    $stmt->bindParam(':keyword', $keyword, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();   
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $row_array['id'] = $row['id'];
        $row_array['user'] = utf8_encode($row['username']);
        array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
    }
} else {
    // Do something else
}
```